# Solr: dismax query parser doesn't support AND OR than why i am getting result

Tags: solr

According to the Solr documentation, [Dismax Query Parser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser) doesn't support **AND** not **OR** in queries. However if I run one of the following queries:

```
http://xx.xx.Xx.xx:yyyy/solr/select?q=Pakistan%20OR%20India&wt=json&indent=true&defType=dismax

http://xx.xx.Xx.xx:yyyy/solr/select?q=Pakistan&wt=json&start=0&rows=20&indent=true&fl=content,url,title&fq=(title:[''+TO+*]+AND+url:[''+TO+*]+AND+content:[''+TO+*])&fq=group:ur_blogs&defType=dismax
```

I get results.

My question is: dismax doesn't support *AND* or *OR* in '**q**' parameter or in the entire query?

Comment: Do you get a hit in the first query if you just use one query term? Have you tried using just "Pakistan India" and q.op=OR? Have you tried providing the fields to query in `qf`?  What are you trying to to with the last query (`['' TO *]`)?

Comment: title:["" to *] is used as a filter that title shouldn't be empty. Actually my question is i should get an error for using AND or OR for building query with using defType=dismax (DISMAX Query Parser). Why am i not getting one

Answer (score 0):

As per description provided in link https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser

"The DisMax query parser supports an extremely simplified subset of the Lucene QueryParser syntax. As in Lucene, quotes can be used to group phrases, and +/- can be used to denote mandatory and optional clauses. All other Lucene query parser special characters (except AND and OR) are escaped to simplify the user experience."